# java - toString using lazy-value string

Tags: java, tostring

I recently had the following thoughts: when you define your object and override toString method, that might be called multiple times during the program execution. I am not sure about how certain UI components refresh themselves (does JTable upon refresh calls each cell-member toString method) or whether debugger calls toString every time when you step on instruction that modifies the object etc. Anyway, I was thinking whether it would be beneficial to define a lazily evaluated String as our to String definition if our structure is IMMUTABLE:

```
private String toString;
//.. definitions of many components, sets, lists which won't change

public String toString(){
   if (toString == null) // instantiate
   return toString;
}
```

Does the above is worth doing?

Comment: Wont make a difference because String Objects are immutable anyway.

Comment: Useless 'cause IIRC on return from method, a new String object will be allocated,

Comment: if you call toString and each time you generate a new String, you might spend substantail time iterating through your internal collections, building up a string and then returning a new object, shich is useless, as it is exactly the same as the previous one. That's my rationale

Comment: Then yes, it is reasonable. But the answer to the question is entirely dependant on what's happening in the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string creation process is long and the created string is often used, you should store it. If not, it depends on how many times you will call the `toString()` method (always the same old war between memory and CPU time)

If your classe is immutable and you know that the `toString()` method will be called at least once, you should instanciate the string in the constructor (or in the factory), instead of always checking.

Answer (score 0):

The standard rules of optimisation come into play here.

1. Don't do it.
2. (For experts only) Don't do it yet - at least not until you've got profiling information illustrating why it's a problem that needs solving.

You're losing clarity and maintainability for performance reasons, so quantify what those performance reasons are and whether they're worth the cost.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to worry about this due to Javas String Literal Pool. Assuming that you are not creating lots of unique strings Java will traverse your code on loading of the class file or initialization and find string, adding them to the String Literal Pool.

This is a great article and overview on this with nice diagrams - [String Literal Pool Overview](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html)

Other suggestions are to use StringBuffers as the independent parts would not added to the buffer only the output string.

Making StringBuffer static would also avoid creating a new object each time, but it really depends on how often you call toString().

If this is really a bottle neck running a profiler as Tom Johnson suggested would be the next direction to take.